# UNLOAD table DB2 with header With JCL

Tags: db2, mainframe, jcl, unload

I'm doing UNLOAD of my DB2 table with JCL using `dsntiaul`.

I want to UNLOAD my DB2 table with the name of columns on the first line of my dataset.

Comment: You need to use DSNTEP2 program if you want the headers of the columns that you are unloading. However, with DSNTEP2 the output LRECL is limited to 133 bytes, so a single record will be split across multiple lines if your table data exceeds that length. Using DSNTEP2, the Integer and Decimal columns are formatted to readable format.